# How to create Pass for Passbook in .NET 2.0 project?

Tags: asp.net, soap, ios6, .net-2.0

We have a restaurant booking iPhone app which uses SOAP web service for exchanging data. Now we want to expose a new service which creates and sends the Pass to iPhone on a request.

Comment: Searching Nuget.org - I found this, which may prove helpful (though i'm not sure about 2.0 compatibility). http://nuget.org/packages/dotnet-passbook/

Comment: Late to the party, but you can use my GitHub lib dotnet-passbook or use my PassVerse platform, which does everything.

Answer (score -1):

add one more web methods in your existing service which will create random password and will send that password. you need to handle the return in string from where you called the web method. for reference check following link for the service which return value.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1d42da/web-service-basics/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what you have mentioned is about passing values using SOAP. What i need to know is how to create pass?

Comment: it will be your own logic either you can create random numbers using random function or any other algorithm it will be yours logic.

Comment: I'm referring to create pass for this http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/#passbook

Comment: This answer has no relevance to the question asked. It's not a library, but this blog post has a **TON** of great information on the Passbook Format. http://www.raywenderlich.com/20734/beginning-passbook-part-1